# Selecting all data from database and manually filtering with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I want to use my own algorithm to filter data retrieved from the database instead of using MySQL LIKE Clause ... But would that have a noticeable effect on the application performance with large amount of data?

Comment: You will use a PDO wrapper class?

Comment: Depends on what the algorithm is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data filtering and searching is definitely a job for the mysql server. Client side data filtering is never a good approach:

When you use the `LIKE` clause the mysql server will filter the data **before** retrieving it to the client (PHP). Therefore the amount of the data transfered is much bigger when you don't use `LIKE`, what is the first performance issue.

The second isssue will be that PHP will use a lot of memory (the whole data set) .

Third issue is the loop that you will need in PHP over *all* records

---

So, you have three good reasons for don't doing that. Note that beside from the `LIKE` clause there are a lot of [string functions in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). They should fit.

Comment: @luk2302 LOL! :D Note that a software component can be a server and a client at the same time. PHP normally acts as a part of the HTTP server, that's right. But when PHP connect's to mysql, then the mysql server is the server and the web server has thge role of the  client

Comment: Of course it takes more time to transfer more data. The network throughput in a data center (between mysql and web server) is likely higher than between DSL user (browser) and web server, but note that there is also much concurrent traffic in a data center.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will have a massive impact on performance if you always retrieve all data and then sort them instead of letting the database deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea. Some of the reasons you should leave the filtering in the DBMS system are:

1. DBMS systems are optimized for these operations
2. this type of operations will cause a lot of overhead in your webserver. Imagine having to do string operations in thousands or millions of strings in PHP. This is done by the DBMS in no-time.
3. carrying large amounts of data from the database to the webserver, and possibly to the browser, will make your application much slower
4. doing filtering with your own PHP code has a much higher probability of introducing bugs and logical errors.

So, leave the DBMS do it's job!